# OpenUI5: offline documentation in SDK not working?

Tags: sapui5

When I download "Latest stable release: 1.28.16 (2015-08-18)" from [here](http://openui5.org/download.html) the documentation is not working. By clicking on \openui5-sdk-1.28.16\index.html the page opens up with empty content.
With older versions I also had non working offline documentation, the navigation page was showing, but the "details pane" was empty.

Is it only with me (using windows 8.1 and chrome Version 44.0.2403.157 m) or is this something general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is related to the browser security when index.html loads its resources ([Same-Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy))

So you have two options:

- deploy the content on a (local) web server (as already pointed in the readme.txt) and open the index.html via http (for instance http://localhost:/openui5-sdk-1.28.16/index.html>)
- run your browser with disabled web security and directly open the index.html

Comment: I used the  ...Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security. Works like a charm. Thanks.