# OpenUI5 offline documentation

Tags: sapui5

When offline I'd like to have the UI5 documentation saved locally.

It appears the docs contained in the runtime [simply reference the official website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297984/openui5-offline-documentation-in-sdk-not-working) and the only other form of downloadable documentation I could find is [a PDF from SAP](https://help.sap.com/OpenUI5_PDF/OpenUI5.pdf) which is indeed well structured and cross-referenced.

Still, I wonder: is there a packaged version of the [UI5 documentation](https://openui5.org/documentation/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Node modules for OpenUI5, I expected to find a separate package for the documentation: there is none. Serving the unzipped [SDK](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/releases/download/1.78.1/openui5-sdk-1.78.1.zip) with any local webserver works just fine.